# Better way to find all path in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a list of connection like the following:

| Predecessor | Successor |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| B | D |
| D | E |
| C | F |
| I | J |
| J | I |
| J | K |

And I try to create of each root node all the possible path like the following:

| Root | Successor |
| --- | --- |
| A | `[A, B, D, E]` |
| A | `[A, C, F]` |
| I | `[I, J, K]` |

So I came up with the following code:

```
# Creating list of root (no predecessor) and tail (no successor) nodes: 
root_nodes = df.select(F.col("Predecessor").join(df.select(F.col("Successor")), [ F.col("Predecessor") == F.col("Successor")], 'leftanti').dropDuplicates()

end_nodes = df.select(F.col("Successor").join(df.select(F.col("Predecessor")), [ F.col("Predecessor") == F.col("Successor")], 'leftanti').dropDuplicates()


# We start from all the root node, who all have at least 1 successor
Result = root_nodes

# Adding an array column to list all the nodes in this path 
Result = Result.withColumn("All_nodes", F.array(F.col("Material")))

# Add the first successor element to create the structure of the dataframe:
Result = Result.join(
    df.select(['Predecessor', 'Successor']).dropDuplicates(),
    [F.col("Root") == F.col("Predecessor")],
    'left'
    ).drop('Predecessor')
Result = Result.withColumnRenamed('Successor', 'iter_0')
Result = Result.withColumn("All_nodes", F.array_union(F.col("All_nodes"), F.array(F.col("iter_0"))))

Result = Result.join(
    df.select(['Predecessor', 'Successor']).dropDuplicates(),
    [
        F.col("iter_0") == F.col("Predecessor"),
        F.col("Root") != F.col("material_1"),
        ~F.array_contains(F.col("All_nodes"), F.col("Successor"))
    ],
    'left'
    ).drop('Predecessor')
Result = Result.withColumnRenamed('Successor', 'iter_1')
Result = Result.withColumn("All_nodes", F.array_union(F.col("All_nodes"), F.array(F.col("iter_1"))))

# loop until all successor don't have any successor anymore
have_succ = True
i = 0
while have_succ:
    # Create all name for this iteration --> iter_N
    anti_pred = "iter_" + str(i)
    pred = "iter_" + str(i + 1)
    succ = "iter_" + str(i + 2)
    Result = Result.join(
        df.select(['Predecessor', 'Successor']).dropDuplicates(),
        [
            F.col(pred) == F.col("Predecessor"),
            F.col(anti_pred) != F.col("Predecessor"),
            ~F.array_contains(F.col("All_nodes"), F.col("Successor"))
        ],
        'left'
        ).drop('Predecessor')
    Result = Result.withColumnRenamed('Successor', succ)
    Result = Result.withColumn("All_nodes", F.array_union(F.col("All_nodes"), F.array(F.col(succ))))

    # increment i
    i += 1

    # Check if last column if full of null value (no more successor) to stop the loop
    if Result.select(F.col(succ)).filter(~F.col(succ).isNull()).distinct().count() == 0:
        print("break")
        have_succ = False

    # Add an escape condition in case of infinite loop
    elif i > 300:
        have_succ = False

    else:
        print("Continue", i, " -- > ", (i+1))

return Result
```

Which give me a result which look like that:

| Root | all_nodes | iter_0 | iter_1 | iter_2 | iter_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | `[A, B, D, E]` | B | D | E | `null` |
| A | `[A, C, F]` | C | F | `null` | `null` |
| I | `[I, J, K]` | J | K | `null` | `null` |

Which is what I'm looking for but I think there is a better way to do it as when I execute it on larger dataframe it will performe more than 100 join this way

Have you any way to improve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are specific libraries to work with graphs (the kind of data representation that seems you are working with). Please take a look to [Graphframes shortest-path algorithm](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/user-guide.html#shortest-paths) This library works on top of `spark`.

Comment: thank you for the library, it seems to solve some of the issue, but only if I know in advance the start and linked ends of this start, or did I get it wrong ?